# How to keep Displays scale 200%?

Tags: display, vmware-workstation, scale-mode

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on VMware Workstation Pro 16. Everything works fine. But the icon looks really small. I'd like to enlarge it by 200%. So I do `Settings`->`Displays`->`Scale`->`200%`and apply it.

The problem is every time I stretch the window or restart the system, the scale changes back automatically. Is there any way I can keep the scale unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22 it worked this way:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/90_hidpi.gschema.override
```

Set scaling factor:

```
[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
scaling-factor=2
```

Recompile + reboot

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo reboot
```

Source: https://kaanlabs.com/ubuntu-set-scaling-factor-to-200-percent/

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution. This re-scaling is very annoying and this solution worked for me for VMware 17 player running VM Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop amd64.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 when I change scale with Settings and restart my system it’s still 200%…